# Showing top nav links only to users that have access

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am working with SharePoint online. From a navigation perspective, I am leveraging Managed Metadata navigation to show links to certain sites which obviously is visible to everyone at the moment.

One of the challenges I have is, these links should be visible to only the users that they have access to them (not everyone). If a user doesn't have access to one of the links in top nav then he/she should not be seeing that link in the top nav. Is this possible to implement in SPO and if so then what would be the best way to achieve?

I am open to using other type of navigation as well.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use Structural Navigation and set your permission whatever you want.
Step1.Activate SharePoint Server Publishing Feature on your site collection level. (these features take little time. 
Step 2. You can set audience targetting specific menus depending on your permissions.
as well as you can set your menus/links to open in a new window like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Managed Metadata navigation, these links should be visible to the users who have permission on the term set and terms. If a user doesn't have access to one of the links but he has permission on the term set and terms, he can see the links.

You can Use Structural Navigation, activate "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode" site collection feature, these links should be visible to only the users that they have access to them (not everyone). Or you can set target audience on these links to limit which users can see those links.